# Trouble understanding how to get rid of a table scan in a basic MYSQL explain example

Tags: mysql, explain

I'm trying to optimize a very basic MYSQL example and I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the below query from doing a table scan when referencing the column uid.  Using explain, tt shows a possible key correctly but doesn't actually use the key and scans all the rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `barId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `barId` (`barId`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
)

explain 
select   count(uid) as userCount 
FROM Foo
WHERE barId = 1
GROUP BY barId

id  select_type table type possible_keys  key   rows  Extra 
1   SIMPLE      Foo   ALL  barId          NULL   4    Using where
```

Sample data

```
id,barId,uid
1,1,1
2,1,2
3,1,3
4,2,4
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` is unnecessary with `barID = 1`

Comment: sure... however still doing table scan without it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like MySQL is being smart and realizing it would take more time to use the index with a table that small?

- When I EXPLAIN it empty, the key is "barId".
- With 4 rows (your
  sample data), key is NULL.
- With 4096 rows (I ran INSERT SELECT to
  itself a handful of times), key returns to "barID".

From the Manual at the [bottom](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html).

> Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables
>   where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query
>   needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than
>   working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even
>   if not all the rows are needed for the query.